# How to select the comparison of two columns as one column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I cannot figure out how to add a column to my SELECT query indicating whether two columns contain the same data in Oracle.

I would like to write a query like:

```
select column1, column2, column1=column2 from table
```

and, if I have this table:

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
| value1  | value1  |
| value2  | value3  |
| value4  | value4  |
+---------+---------+
```

get a result like:

```
+---------+---------+-----------------+
| column1 | column2 | column1=column2 |
+---------+---------+-----------------+
| value1  | value1  | true            |
| value2  | value3  | false           |
| value4  | value4  | true            |
+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

What is the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: For whatever reason, Oracle SQL doesn't have a boolean datatype unlike MySQL. I really wonder why.

Comment: whell, true|false, 0|1, whathever makes the point :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you want to consider null values equality too, try the following

```
select column1, column2, 
   case
      when column1 is NULL and column2 is NULL then 'true'  
      when column1=column2 then 'true' 
      else 'false' 
   end 
from table;
```

Answer (score 16):

I stopped using `DECODE` several years ago because it is non-portable. Also, it is less flexible **and** less readable than a `CASE/WHEN`.

However, there is one neat "trick" you can do with decode because of how it deals with NULL. In decode, NULL is equal to NULL. That can be exploited to tell whether two columns are different as below.

```
select a, b, decode(a, b, 'true', 'false') as same
  from t;

     A       B  SAME
------  ------  -----
     1       1  true
     1       0  false
     1          false
  null    null  true
```

Answer (score 10):

```
select column1, coulumn2, case when colum1=column2 then 'true' else 'false' end from table;
```

HTH

Comment: Short and nice!