# Compare separate columns in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm looking for the mongoid equivalent to:
[How to select the comparison of two columns as one column in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827751/compare-two-columns-in-a-select)

I can't seem to find any documentation or examples comparing columns within the same query.  Is this just not possible in Mongoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you need to drop down to the mongodb ruby driver to do this and it will potentially be very slow as it is a javascript query that will not use an index:

```
Model.collection.find_one({"$where" => 'this.name == this.name2'})
```

Which is equivalent to third shell command here.:

```
> db.collection.insert({name: "awesome", name2: "awesome"})
> db.collection.insert({name: "awesome", name2: "awesome2"})
> db.collection.find('this.name == this.name2')
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"), "name" : "awesome", "name2" : "awesome" }
> (line shown to signify end of results)
```

Note: if a document does not have key `name` and that same document also does not have key `name2` that this will return true because null == null.

Comment: From what I can tell, Model.collection.find_one() only takes the regular selectors, not arbitrary javascript.

Comment: I needed to change $where to "$where" and then it works, thanks.